# How to process each contours?

Tags: opencv

[image]

I'm planning to try contours on some image. Lets say I have three object after binarized. Does it mean I have three contours? If yes, how can I process every each of the contours?

Thank you.

Updated: I need to process blobs #1 first. FYI, the blobs are not exactly like a quadrilateral. If tried using cvSetImageROI but blob #2 and part of blob #3 might appear in the cropped image. I was thinking if contours can extract only blob #1 without having blob #2 and #3. Is it clear with the explanation? (using C API not C++ API).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each `contour` is array (`std::vector`) of `Points`. When you call `findContours` it returns array of contours in your binary image. Here's simple example:

```
vector<vector<Point> > contours;
vector<Vec4i> hierarchy;
Mat src;

findContours(src, contours, hierarchy, RETR_TREE, CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);

for(size_t i = 0; i<contours.size(); i++)
{
    //process contours[i]
    for (size_t j=0; j<contours[i].size(); j++)
    {
        int x = contours[i][j].x;
        int y = contours[i][j].y;
        // process point j in contour i
    }
}
```

[Here's official OpenCV manual](http://opencv.itseez.com/doc/tutorials/imgproc/shapedescriptors/find_contours/find_contours.html).

Comment: In the for loop means I can process individually each contours received? Each contours represent an object?

Comment: @MizukiKai each contour is array of points - read my first sentence, please. Yes you can process each conour in the loop. See update of my answer.

Comment: @MizukiKai hierarchy – Optional output vector containing information about the image topology. It has as many elements as the number of contours. For each contour contours[i] , the elements hierarchy[i][0] , hiearchy[i][1] , hiearchy[i][2] , and hiearchy[i][3] are set to 0-based indices in contours of the next and previous contours at the same hierarchical level: the first child contour and the parent contour, respectively. If for a contour i there are no next, previous, parent, or nested contours, the corresponding elements of hierarchy[i] will be negative.

Comment: If I have the contours(array of points) of the 1st object. How can I copy all the point of the 1st object only and paste it on a new blank image?

Comment: @MizukiKai there's method `drawContours`. See my last sentence. And please, read that tutorial. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the function `cv::findContours`for this. It will give you a hierarchized list of the contours of your image.

More information in the [doc](http://opencv.itseez.com/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html?highlight=contour#void%20findContours%28InputOutputArray%20image,%20OutputArrayOfArrays%20contours,%20OutputArray%20hierarchy,%20int%20mode,%20int%20method,%20Point%20offset%29).

**EDIT**
Hierarchichized list means a tree-like structure.
If there is a contour inside another one (think of a plate with holes for example) then you can ask the function to return you a structure that preserves the inclusion information, or a flat structure if you prefer.

Comment: I did try using cvFindContours. Hierarchy list means?

Comment: I've updated the answer. Please be more informative about your problems if finContours did not work for you!

Comment: I was trying to use contours to extract only the shape. but as you know, the shape different everytime other input image given. wondering if contours a good choice rather than using cvblobs..

Comment: If you just want to extract each individual object, then you may consider using connected component detection instead.

Comment: Yup. I did try that but for cases such as above image, if I use CCA which i need to set image roi (rectangle) it will also include blob #2 and #3. Therefore, it might not suitable in this type of cases. :(

Comment: In your case, you cannot use a rectangle ROI (it's obvious in your example image). But on the other hand you can use a mask w/ 0's and 1's where a pixel is processed only if non-zero. You still have to loop over all the pixels, but only the pixels of interest to you will be used.